# Proving that $T(B(x,2\epsilon))\cap B(y,2\epsilon) \neq \emptyset $

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$H$ Hilbert space.

$x,y \in H$ and $T\in L(H)$

1) $T(B(x,\epsilon))\cap B(0,\epsilon) \neq \emptyset $

2) $T(B(0,\epsilon))\cap B(y,\epsilon) \neq \emptyset $

3) $T(B(x,2\epsilon))\cap B(y,2\epsilon) \neq \emptyset $

I would like to prove that 1) and 2) $\implies$ 3)

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need that $H$ is a Hilbert space, any normed space will do. Let's for shortness write $B_r$ for $B(0,r) = \{ x : \lVert x\rVert < r\}$.

What we need are

- $B(x,r) = x + B_r$ for all $x$ and $r > 0$, and
- $B_r + B_s = B_{r+s}$ for $r, s > 0$.

So 1) says there is a $z_1 \in B_\varepsilon$ with $\lVert T(x + z_1)\rVert < \varepsilon$. 2) says there is a $z_2 \in B_\varepsilon$ with $\lVert T(z_2) - y\rVert < \varepsilon$.

Considering that, what can you say about $x + z_1 + z_2$?

Comment: Alright, I need to find a $z_3 \in B_{2\epsilon}$ such that $\lVert T(x + z_3)-y\rVert < 2\varepsilon$

and $z_3=z_1+z_2$ works. 

Thanks for the insight.